# Auto scroll div

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a `div` scroll to the `bottom`, then back to the `top` and repeat infinitely, currently I can only find how to make it scroll to the bottom:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#scrolldiv').animate({
   scrollTop: $('#scrolldiv')[0].scrollHeight}, 30000);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add a callback function to the animate function

```js
function scroll(down) {
    $("body").animate({
        scrollTop: down ? $("body")[0].scrollHeight : 0
    }, 1000, function () { //a callback function
        scroll(!down);
    });
}
$(scroll);
```

```css
body {
  height: 3000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```